# How to tell if a UITableView's cell is visible on the screen

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I'm writing an Objective-C app for iOS 8. I was wondering if anyone knows how to tell if a `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView` is on-screen.

For example, if the y value of the `UITableView`'s `contentOffset` is 0 (meaning that the `UITableView` is scrolled to the top) and I programmatically select row 2, I don't want to scroll at all because row 2 is already visible (assuming that the `UITableView` is large enough to show at least 3 rows). However, if I programmatically select row 10 (which is off screen), I want to programmatically scroll to that row.

This is the code I use to scroll to the selected row:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                              animated:NO];
```

Now, I just need to nest that code inside an if-statement that checks to see if the cell at the currently-selected row is fully visible on-screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` -- "Return Value -- An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range."  You might need additional logic to assure that the cell is *fully* visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want the selected row to be visible with the least amount of movement, use the method made just for that:

```
[self.tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

From the docs for `UITableViewScrollPositionNone`:

> The table view scrolls the row of interest to be fully visible with a minimum of movement. If the row is already fully visible, no scrolling occurs. For example, if the row is above the visible area, the behavior is identical to that specified by UITableViewScrollPositionTop. This is the default.

Comment: I like this answer, but I can't really use it because I just realized I'm not technically selecting a row (it's complicated). It's still the best answer to my actual question IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForCell:tableView.visibleCells.firstObject];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Comment: Although this didn't actually answer my question, it did inform me that there is an actual list of visible cells. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ask to the tableview if a view is shown at specific time.
What you can do is to be delegate for this tableview and implement this methods:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can implementing this methods track the uitableview showing at that moment.